# Setup WPS on TL-WR703N

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wps

I have a TP Link TL-WR703N Router that I am trying to setup as an educational tool to teach Wireless Security.

As part of this, I want to setup an SSID that uses WPS as its authentication method, however I can't seem to find anything online that explains how you can set this up.

Has anyone found anything online themselves, or set this up at all, and can offer some advice?

The router configuration is as follows:

- Running OpenWrt Barrier Breaker 14.07 / LuCI Trunk (0.12+svn-r10530)
- Kernel Version 3.10.49

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenWrt Wiki section on WPS](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless#wpsoptions), there are some non-default libraries you will need to include to support WPS:

- Support for WPS is provided by packages wpad and hostapd-utils.
  Default package wpad-mini is not enough.
- WPS is possible only when encryption PSK is selected.

it also gives the following minimal steps to get WPS working on OpenWrt firmware, including the two steps above (obviously, you would ssh into your device for these steps):

1. Add option wps_pushbutton '1'  to a config wifi-iface section that
   is configured for WPA2-PSK
2. opkg update
3. opkg remove wpad-mini
4. opkg install wpad hostapd-utils
5. reboot

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mcgyver5, I have tried setting the wps_pushbutton '1'  option before, however it said that I needed to do it against all interfaces on the router.  That was fine, WPS was then showing as enabled on my list of available connections.

However, when trying to connect to the actual wps ssid, it connected me to the wrong one (another SSID that was configured for WPS2-PSK for a different test).

Any other ideas as to how we can achieve enabling WPS for just one interface?